# Split multiline string by lines and comma and place the parts into DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, split

I want to split and transpose a multiline string from one DataGridView(dgvObs) to separate rows and columns in another DataGridView(dgvSm).
This code works, but - maybe there is a better solution:

```
object val = dgvObs.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value;
if (val == null) return;

string text = val.ToString();
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(text))
{
   string line;
   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      string[] divLine = line.Split(',');
      dgvSm.Rows.Add(divLine);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wether or not there is a BETTER way, I do not know, but whatever class or function which takes your text and turns it into a datagrid is going to do the same thing more or less.  My thought is that since you did it this way, you dont have the overhead of object/class declaration.

Comment: My dilemma is about a shorter way. Somethin like: foreach (splitedline in...)... dgvSm.Rows.Add(...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter you say? Try this:

```
var a = dgvObs.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value;

if (a == null) return;

foreach (String s in a.ToString().Split(','))
{
   dgvSm.Rows.Add(s);
}
```

COMMENT EDIT:

This will read the multiline, split it via regular expressions and then do what my original code did. Simply add the `dgvSm.Rows.Add(s);` line into the nested foreach statement.

```
var a = @"I'm a cat, woof.
                    bombs, away";

var result = Regex.Split(a, "\r\n|\r|\n");

foreach (var z in result)
{
   foreach (String sString in z.Split(','))
   {
      var asaa = sString.Trim();
   }
}
```

Comment: KreepN - starting string is multiline, and inside each line there is comma separated values. The goal is each line to place into dgvRow, and each comma separated value - into dgvColumn. Your code creates a dgvRow for each csv, and not for each line. AnyWay, ThankYoy.

Comment: Check the Edit if you wish to see a modified version of code per your comment.